# How can I DC analyze these values in netlist simulation

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, pspice, analysis, netlists

For my lab report I have to DC analyze a circuit for these specific VDD values.
Is there any way to get simulation output for just these values? Because when I write
.DC VDD 0.2V 10V 0.2V or .DC VDD 0.2V 10V 2V
I'm getting a lot of unnecessary or missing outputs  in the simulation.

[image: VDD values]

Comment: I expect there will be several ways of doing this.

Comment: Can you show us the circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using LTspice, then you can use the following syntax:

```
.dc V1 list 0.2 0.4 0.5 0.7 1 2 4 6 8 10
```

[image]

Comment: Or tell me what simulation program you are using? (pspice, ngspice, etc.) And what CAD do you use? (For example, KiCad uses ngspice, but the functionality is cut off)